# How to capture content of an input element and test if it is characters betwween letters a-z A-Z with a space berween two words

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, input, try-catch

i have this this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").focus(function(){
        $(this).css('outline-color','#559FFF');
        $(this).blur(function(){
            $(this).css("outline-color","#FF0000");
        });
    });
    $("input").click(function(){
     var value = $(this).val(function(){
         $(this).html("");
      });
    });
    $(".awesome").click(function(){
        var toStore = $("input[name=name]").val();
        if((toStore===/[a-zA-Z]/)===true){
        $("#contain").children().fadeOut(1000);
        $("#contain").delay(5000).queue(function(){
            $("#contain").append("<p>welcome : " + toStore + " </p>");
    });
        }else{
            alert("You Must Put a Valid Name");
        }
});
});
```

i want my code to test and catch the value of my input and if the value is a characters 
between a-z including capitalize with a space between two words like: "FirstName LastName"
if its ok thne procced to:

```
$("#contain").children().fadeOut(1000);
        $("#contain").delay(5000).queue(function(){
            $("#contain").append("<p>welcome : " + toStore + " </p>");
    });
```

else alert the user that he must put valid characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this regex should work:

```
if (/^[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+$/.test(toStore)) {

}
```

and should be put in place of your `if((toStore===/[a-zA-Z]/)===true){`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tDVWk/

This checks that the input follows this:

- Starts with 1 or more alphabetic characters (any can be uppercase or lowercase)
- Contains a space after the previous set of characters
- Ends with 1 or more alphabetic characters (any can be uppercase or lowercase)

If you want to be more strict and require that each name start with an uppercase letter and the rest be lowercase, you can use:

```
if (/^[A-Z][a-z]? [A-Z][a-z]?$/.test(toStore)) {

}
```

But that isn't ideal, as names are very different and could easily be something like "McLovin"...where this second example would definitely fail. Hopefully my first example should complete what you need.

Of course, there's always the debate that you shouldn't restrict something like this so much. What if their name is more than just a first and last? What if they have a suffix, like "III" (or actually "3"), designating they are the third of their family with that name? What if people want to include their middle name (on purpose or accident)? It might make more sense for you to use two textboxes for each name, making it more clear for the user. That way, all you have to do is validate that each is filled in (and maybe only has alphabetic characters). Then again, I'm not sure what your requirements are and what this textbox you already have is for :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?   You'll need to add your code where you need it.

```
<script>
 function validateInput(obj, e){
    var code;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;
    var character = String.fromCharCode(code);
    var AllowRegex  = /^[\ba-zA-Z,\s-\f\n\r\t\v]$/;
    if (AllowRegex.test(character)){ 
        return true;
    }
    else{
    alert('!');
        return false;
    }
    }
</script>

<input id="input1" onkeydown=" return validateInput(this,event) "/>
```